# How to show only date from DataGridView to label

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datagridview

I am working on C# and sql server. I saved date using DateTimePicker to sql. Now I am using DataGridView to show record then by selecting a row that data is shown on labels. Problem is I want to show only date but through the following method time is also coming along.

```
 private void datagridpatient_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        lblgridpbirthday.Text = row.Cells["Birthday"].Value.ToString();
    }
```

How to show only date?

Comment: Try using `DateTime.Parse(row.Cells["Birthday"].Value).ToShortDateString())`.

Comment: Shows red zigzag line on "row.Cells["Birthday"].Value" and says cannot convert object to String

Comment: What about `DateTime.Parse(row.Cells["Birthday"].Value.ToString()).ToShortDateStrin‌​g())`, assuming `row.Cells["Birthday"].Value` is `object`?

Comment: Bang-on @TetsuyaYamamoto... post your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

```
 blgridpbirthday.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["Birthday"].Value).ToShortDateStrin‌​g();
```

or

```
lblgridpbirthday.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["Birthday"].Value).ToString("YourDateFormatHere");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below,

```
lblgridpbirthday.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["Birthday"].Value).ToString("YourDateFormatHere");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 var birthday =  Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["Birthday"].Value);
 lblgridpbirthday.Text = birthday.Date.ToString();
```